# PHP unexpected result of float to int type cast

Tags: php, casting, floating-point, type-conversion

I'trying to convert a float to an int value in php:

```
var_dump((int)(39.3 * 100.0)); //Returns 3929 but should be 3930!
var_dump((int)(39.2 * 100.0)); //Returns 3920
```

I can use ceil to make it work but can somebody explain this to me?

```
var_dump((int)ceil(39.3 * 100.0)); //Returns 3930
```

Comment: One quick note, hopefully you are expecting 3930, rather than 3939.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is because numbers that have a finite representation in base 10 may or may not have an exact representation in the floating point representation PHP uses.

See

```
>php -r "echo var_dump(sprintf('%.40F', 39.3 * 100.0));"
string(45) "3929.9999999999995452526491135358810424804688"
```

Since `int` always rounds the number down, a small error in the representation makes the cast round it one number down that you would otherwise expect.

Consider using [`round`](http://php.net/round) instead.

Comment: you shouldn't use neither String nor round, bcmul functions are there for a purpose.

Answer (score 17):

**This might be late but the proper way to do it is as follows:**

```
(int) bcmul("39.3", "100.0"); // 3930
(int) bcmul("39.2", "100.0"); // 3920
```

and for dealing with digits / calculation for floats, or anything that involves money transaction, you should never use directly multiplication/division + casting.

please refer to this as well:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php

**notice: the casting in my answer is just to convert String to Int, (you don't need to do it)**

Comment: Note: bcmul expects strings as params, and will throw TypeError with strict types.

Comment: @SzabolcsPáll thanks for the correction, at the original time of writing PHP 5 was still dominant, but your comment is valid in all cases

Answer (score 4):

```
// gives: int(3930)
var_dump(intval((39.3 * 100.0) . ''));
```

or, for use with a function:

```
function floatToInteger ($fValue)
{
    return (intval(($fValue + 0) . ''));
}

// gives: int(3930)
var_dump(floatToInteger(39.3 * 100.0));
```