# PHP two numbers after decimal point

Tags: php, numbers

I have a float number in PHP : `0.966666666667` 
I would like to print it like : `0.96` I used round() and `number_format()` but they give me both
`0.97` is there a function to do that please ?

Comment: Please research prior to asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668628/truncate-float-numbers-with-php

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$num = 0.966666;
$num = floor($num * 100) / 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this I've found is this:

```
//$val - the value to truncate
//$dist - the number of digits after to decimal place to keep
function truncate($val, $dist) {
    //get position of digit $dist places after decimal point
    $pos = strpos($val,'.');

    if($pos !== false) {//if $val is actually a float

        //get the substring starting at the beginning
        //and ending with the point $dist after the
        //decimal, inclusive -- convert to float.
        $val = floatval(substr($val, 0, $pos + 1 + $dist));

    }          

    return $val;
}
```

Then just call `truncate($YOUR_NUM, 2);`.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12710283/3281590