# PHP float comparison

Tags: php, if-statement, comparison, floating

I have the following PHP code in which I want to compare two decimal numbers. I have read in the PHP documentation that floating point numbers have limited precision.

```
$a = 0.0;

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $a += 0.1;
}

var_dump($a);
echo gettype($a);

if ($a === 1.0) {
    echo "IF";
} else {
    echo "ELSE";
}
```

When I compare variable $a with 1.0, it always returns false, and the result will be 'ELSE'. My question is how I can get the code above working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just do it this way:

//just a check if it is float, than round it to 1 decimal number and compare

```
if(is_float($a)){
    echo 'not a float';
    $a = round($a,1);
}
```

and output will be 'IF'

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked before, see [Compare floats in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3148991/4652136).

Basically you need to calculate the difference and see if it is small enough to be acceptable as "equal".

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$a = 0.0;

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $a += 0.1;


$a=number_format($a,1);
//echo gettype($a);
//echo $a.'<br>';
if (floatval($a) === 1.0)
    echo "IF";
else
    echo "ELSE";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to make the comparison work I would truncate $a to one decimal place and format $a to a string with the required precision and compare it to "1.0".

To truncate $a I suggest [reading this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668628/truncate-float-numbers-with-php) .

Or you can use $a as an integer. Them instead of incrementing by 0.1 use 1. And use 10 in the final comparison.