# Limit length of number

Tags: php

I have a value in database which contains 20 numbers, example :
1.1234567891011223

I want to limit the echoed value to 1.123 or 1.12 only instead of this long number..

How can I do that in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for either the **[`round`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)** function:

```
$long_number = 1.1234567891011223;
$formatted_number = round($long_number, 2);
echo $formatted_number; // 1.12
```

Or the **[`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)** function:

```
$long_number = 1.1234567891011223;
$formatted_number = number_format($long_number, 2, '.', '');
echo $formatted_number; // 1.12
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

use `round` function

```
echo round(1.1234567891011223,2); // output: 1.12
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are searching for? http://php.net/manual/de/function.number-format.php

use it like that:

```
<?php 
    $a = 1.1234567891011223;
    echo number_format ( $a , 3 , '.', '');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php). Below is an example from another post [@Nineoclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668628/truncate-float-numbers-with-php) This function finds the decimal and rounds the number. Rounding the number will shorten it.

```
truncate(1.1234567891011223, 2)

function truncate($val,$p = 0)
{
  $strpos = strpos($val, '.');
  return $p < 0 ? round($val,$p) : ($strpos ? (float)substr($val,0,$strpos+1+$p) : $val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) for this

```
$formatted = sprintf("%01.2f", $longNum);
```

Or if you're just going to echo it and don't need the variable, [printf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php)

```
printf("%01.2f", $longNum);
```