# Wrong Calculation?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is double Multiplication Broken in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420752/is-double-multiplication-broken-in-net)
>   [PHP unexpected result of float to int type cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385685/php-unexpected-result-of-float-to-int-type-cast)

```
echo (int) ( (0.1+0.7) * 10);
```

Gives me answer 7 but not 8.

```
echo (int) ( (0.1+0.8) * 10);
```

Gives answer 9 which is right

whats wrong? can anybody explain

thanx,
-Navi

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385685/php-unexpected-result-of-float-to-int-type-cast

Comment: Yes I know it says .Net but it's the exact same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s normal – There’s a thing called precision while working with floating point numbers. It’s present in most of the modern languages. See here: http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/nfbasic2.html for more information.

`((0.1+0.7) * 10)` is probably something like `7.9999999` and `(int) 7.9999999 = 7`

On the other hand `((0.1+0.8) * 10)` is probably `9.00000001` and `(int)9.00000001 = 9`

> Floating point numbers have limited precision. Although it depends on the system, PHP typically uses the IEEE 754 double precision format, which will give a maximum relative error due to rounding in the order of 1.11e-16. Non elementary arithmetic operations may give larger errors, and, of course, error propagation must be considered when several operations are compounded.
>
> Additionally, rational numbers that are exactly representable as
>   floating point numbers in base 10, like 0.1 or 0.7, do not have an
>   exact representation as floating point numbers in base 2, which is
>   used internally, no matter the size of the mantissa. Hence, they
>   cannot be converted into their internal binary counterparts without a
>   small loss of precision. This can lead to confusing results: for
>   example, floor((0.1+0.7)*10) will usually return 7 instead of the
>   expected 8, since the internal representation will be something like
>   7.9999999999999991118....
>
> So never trust floating number results to the last digit, and do not
>   compare floating point numbers directly for equality. If higher
>   precision is necessary, the arbitrary precision math functions and gmp
>   functions are available.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Comment: Why 0.1 + 0.7 is 7.9999999 but not 0.8?

Comment: i think i knew that but forgot but your explanation reminded me of it again. thanx :-)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
echo (float) ( (0.1+0.7) * 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Float

```
echo (float) ( (0.1+0.7) * 10);
```

it will give you perfect ans

Answer (score 0):

try

```
echo (int) round( ( (0.1+0.7) * 10));
```

This should compensate the floating point computation error.