# PHP Type Casting

Tags: php, casting

So I was asked as part of my homework to cast a *floating point number* to *integer* in **PHP**. Problem is that no such cast is possible according to **[php.net](http://php.net/)** and I myself cannot find the notion behind the question.

Given the following:

```
$float = 1.92;
$float += 2;
```

It'll just substitute them resulting in **3.92** as an output.

---

As far as I could see the possible *(or rather allowed)* casts are as follows:

The casts allowed are:

```
(int), (integer) - cast to integer
(bool), (boolean) - cast to boolean
(float), (double), (real) - cast to float
(string) - cast to string
(array) - cast to array
(object) - cast to object
(unset) - cast to NULL (PHP 5)
```

Is it some sort of trick that they have presented us with or the task is invalid?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP unexpected result of float to int type cast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385685/php-unexpected-result-of-float-to-int-type-cast)

Comment: I don't want to convert it but type cast.

Comment: So why do you think you can't cast a float to an integer?

Comment: kind of the same thing.

Comment: @Mark Baker: Because PHP documentation does not say it could be casted.

Comment: @MikeFonder You quoted it yourself in your post `The casts allowed are: (int), (integer) - cast to integer
`: is ___cast to integer___ so difficult to recognise

Comment: Why is the question titled **PHP Type Casting** if you dont want to cast the value to an int?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was the task to round the float to the nearest whole number? In which case:

```
$float = 1.92;
$float += 2;

echo round($float);
```

outputs 4. Or a straight cast:

```
$float = 1.92;
$float += 2;

echo (int) $float;
```

outputs 3.

Comment: I suppose the second example should be valid and accepted as a solution. I'll proceed with it. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think you can't cast float to int?

```
php > $float = 1.92;
php > var_dump($float);
float(1.92)
php > $int = 2 + (int)$float;
php > var_dump($int);
int(3)
php > $int2 = (int)(2 + $float);
php > var_dump($int2);
int(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always convert the float number to string like for your code

```
$float = 1.92;
$float +=2;
$int = (int)$float;
echo $int;
```

PHP always supports float to integer type casting.